# aws ec2 getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND error code

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, error-code

My aim is to get the instanceId when my script is started. (Cause I want to connect my webserver as backend with the aws elb. This even works when I hardcode the id) So now I try to code a function wich gives me the id.

So what I know is that I need the AWS.metadataService but I don't know how to use it. I found [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/MetadataService.html#request-property) (metaDataService) an [command-line tool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html). I guess I need to combine it like this:

```
var meta  = new AWS.MetadataService();

meta.request("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/", function(err, data){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(data);
});
```

But it produces this error:

```
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 169.254.169.254http 169.254.169.254http:80]
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: '169.254.169.254http',
  host: '169.254.169.254http',
  port: 80 }
```

Any ideas what could fix this? Or at least what causes this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope it helps.

```
var meta  = new AWS.MetadataService({
   host: '169.254.169.254'
});

meta.request('/latest/meta-data/', function(err, data){
   if(err){
      console.log(err);
   }
   console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message rather clearly tells you, you somehow ended up passing in `169.254.169.254http` as the host name, and `169.254.169.254http:80` as the host.  Just to spell this out completely, you probably wanted the host to be `169.254.169.254`. You need to figure out why your request was botched like this, and correct the code or your configuration files so you send what you wanted to send.

`ENOTFOUND` in response to `getaddrinfo` simply means that you wanted to obtain the address of something which doesn't exist or is unknown. Very often this means that you have a typo, or that the information you used to configure your service is obsolete or otherwise out of whack (attempting to reach a private corporate server when you are outside the  corporate firewall, for example).